# How to modify applications.menu file as root?

Tags: unity, root, backtrack

I´m trying to install Backtrack on Ubuntu (with Unity).

I´m stuck trying to modify applications.menu file, because it´s readme only. And I can´t change that using the GUI because it´s greyed out.

How may I make that file read/write from the command line, or access it with gedit as root?

Comment: Sudo nano file-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way wold be:

- Use the following command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

  ```
  sudo -i
  ```

  to get a shell where you have root privileges.
- Then use the following command:

  ```
   xdg-open /usr/share/app-install/desktop/applications.menu
  ```

  to open `applications.menu` file in your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nano

```
sudo nano path/to/file
```

You can also use gedit

```
gksudo gedit path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How may I use gedit in that way? typing first sudo nano gedit? I´ve tried but it won´t open the gedit application...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got enough reputation to answer Rosamunda Rosamunda's comment so I'll just answer here.

Instead of using `sudo nano gedit` use `sudo gedit [path]`.

`sudo` gives you root priviliges

`gedit` means you want to start the program gedit.

and then the path. Example:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/app-install/desktop/applications.menu
```

Just a general Linux tip: you are starting a program every time you type a word in the terminal.

```
[program name] [arguments for the program]
```

so the next line means start the program gedit and the /usr/share/....... argument tells gedit that it have to open that file.

```
gedit /usr/share/app-install/desktop/applications.menu
```

when putting `sudo` infront of the command tells linux that the command should be run with root priviliges.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/app-install/desktop/applications.menu
```